Tengo problemas para leer el contenido de un archivo XML usando PHP
Estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema para llevar registro de compras y ventas, el usuario carga un archivo y se lee la información del archivo.
Mi problema esta en que he tratado de varias maneras y no puedo leer el contenido del archivo XML.
El contenido del archivo es el siguiente:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:autorizacionComprobanteResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.autorizacion">
            <RespuestaAutorizacionComprobante>
                <claveAccesoConsultada>050120240109999999900120011000000002977798736317</claveAccesoConsultada>
                <numeroComprobantes>1</numeroComprobantes>
                <autorizaciones>
                    <autorizacion>
                        <estado>AUTORIZADO</estado>
                        <numeroAutorizacion>0501202401099999999900120011000000002977798736317</numeroAutorizacion>
                        <fechaAutorizacion>2024-03-16T17:53:50-05:00</fechaAutorizacion>
                        <ambiente>PRODUCCIÓN</ambiente>
                        <comprobante>
                            <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><factura id="comprobante" version="1.1.0"><infoTributaria><ambiente>2</ambiente><tipoEmision>1</tipoEmision>

Básicamente lo que quiero leer es el CDATA, el cuerpo de la factura, si elimino las etiquetas de soap puedo leer el archivo pero no puedo decirle eso al usuario final.
Quedo atento muchas Gracias.
PD: Son facturas del SRI Ecuador.

¿Le has echado un ojo a las preguntas que aparecen en la columna derecha como "Relacionados" sobre como leer fichero XML con PHP? Aquí plantean y resuelven un problema parecido al tuyo. Por otro lado, ¿cómo estás leyendo ahora?

Esto es una respuesta de un Servicio Web basado en Soap, como se puede ver aquí: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">. ¿Acaso no estás usando la biblioteca de Soap para enviar peticiones y recibir las respuestas del Servicio Web? Si trabajas con esa herramienta podrás manejar con mayor simplicidad y seguridad los datos.
